# JS function to compare two arrays of numbers that include duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays, set

I'm building a mastermind game. In this game the player needs to guess a secret random number. To make this work I need to have a function that can compare the two arrays and check if there is a match in number and position and/or a match only in the number but not the position.

The problem: This function works well for the most part when there are not repeated numbers in the arrays, but gives me a wrong output when there are repeated numbers.

example:

```
Random -- arr1 = ['5', '5', '3', '4']
Guess -- arr 2 = ['5', '1', '0', '0,]
```

expected result

```
{match: true, exactMatches: 1, matchesByValue: 0}
```

I'm getting this wrong result:

```
{match: true, exactMatches: 1, matchesByValue: 1}
```

Important: matchesByValue means correct number in wrong position. It shouldn't consider numbers that have been already counted as exactMatches.

```
function compareGuessVsRandom(arr1, arr2) {

    // convert the arrays to sets

    const set1 = new Set(arr1);
    const set2 = new Set(arr2);
    let exactMatches = 0;
    let matchesByValue = 0;
    // check if each value in the first array has the same value and position in the second array
    for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
      if (arr1[i] == arr2[i]) {
        exactMatches++;
      } else if (set1.has(arr2[i])) {
        matchesByValue++;
      }
    }

    // if all checks pass, the arrays are a match
    const result = {
      match: true,
      exactMatches: exactMatches,
      matchesByValue: matchesByValue,
    };
    console.log(result);
    return result;
  }
```

Comment: Can't you just return `matchesByValue` subtracted by `exactMatches`?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function compareGuessVsRandom (arr1, arr2) {
    // The list of all the indicies at which there is an exact match
    const exactMatchesList = []

    // The amount of matche by value
    let matchesByValue = 0


    for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++)
        if (arr1[i] === arr2[i])
            exactMatchesList.push(i)


    // Init sets with arrays without the exactly-matched values
    const set1 = new Set(arr1.filter((_, i) => !exactMatchesList.includes(i)))
    const set2 = new Set(arr2.filter((_, i) => !exactMatchesList.includes(i)))

    // If set2 contains an element of set1, increment matchesByValue
    for (const e of set1)
        matchesByValue += set2.has(e)

    // Get the amount of exact matches
    const exactMatches = exactMatchesList.length

    const result = {
        match: exactMatches !== 0 || matchesByValue !== 0,
        exactMatches,
        matchesByValue
    }
    
    return result;
}

const random = [ '5', '5', '3', '4' ]
const guess  = [ '5', '1', '0', '0' ]

console.log(compareGuessVsRandom(random, guess))
```

Answer (score 0):

The has method returns true if set1 contains the specified element. So regardless of whether an exact match has occurred or not, it will increment 'matchesByValue' even for a match at the index with the exact match.

For example, in a scenario where arr2 has [5,5,0,0]. The first '5'. will increment 'exactMatches' but the second one will also increment 'matchesByValue' by matching it with index 0 of set1.

You can eliminate duplicate matches by comparing indexes of the two types of matches.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This function solved the problem with duplicates. Thanks everyone!

```
//helper function to count how many values two arrays have in common
const countCommonValuesOfArrays = (arr1, arr2) =>
  arr1.reduce((a, c) => a + arr2.includes(c), 0);

export function compareGuessVsRandom(guesses, random) {
  //check for duplicates
  let perfectMatch = [];
  let equalValues = [];
  let unmatchedGuesses = [];
  let unmatchedRandom = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < guesses.length; i++) {
    if (guesses[i] === random[i]) {
      perfectMatch++;
    } else {
      unmatchedGuesses.push(guesses[i]);
      unmatchedRandom.push(random[i]);
    }
  }
  equalValues = countCommonValuesOfArrays(unmatchedGuesses, unmatchedRandom);
  return {
    gameMatch: perfectMatch === random.length,
    perfectMatch: perfectMatch,
    equalValues: equalValues,
  };
}
```